# Linking Kim Walisch Primes Libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, linker

I am trying to use **Kim Walisch** primes libraries found on github (primecount, primesum & primesieve). For start, I tried to use primecount - https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount .

Not being an expert C/C++ programmer, nor a Visual Studio user, I searched for the process on the internet - Youtube and here (Stackoverflow). I downloaded the github extension for Visual Studio, and then cloned the repository from github. The repository is saved on "C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos". I then understood I need to 'link' the library to my current project. I did the following:

1. Right click on my **project name** found to the left --> **Properties** at the bottom --> **configuration properties** --> **C/C++** --> **Additional Include Directories** --> and here I just copy the path: **"C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\primecount\include"**
2. Right click on my **project name** found to the left --> **Properties** --> **configuration properties** --> **Linker** --> **General** --> **Additional Library Directories** --> and here I just copy another path: **"C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\primecount\Primes\Primes\Debug"**
3. Right click on my **project name** found to the left --> **Properties** --> **configuration properties** --> **Linker** --> **Input** --> **Additional Dependencies** --> and here I just copy the same path: **"C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\primecount\Primes\Primes\Debug"**

There aren't any .lib or dll files, so I simply tried varius of other things. I tried to copy the paths with/without quotes. Tried to use different paths for each of these 3. I think I am getting the first one right, but not the linker. I keep getting errors like "LNK1107" "LNK1120" and most often "LNK1104". Different errors occur when I change the paths. In the link above, it says the following contains more information: https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount/blob/master/doc/libprimecount.md and at the bottom of this link, it says "Linking: c++ -O2 primes.cpp -lprimecount" so I tried to use this in a way as well (not sure if it's meant for this). I tried to locate the 'library', which from my understand is what I need to link, but I can't find it anywhere in the folder. The closest I found are the above paths, that contain an **obj.** file, but still it doesn't work and I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong here. Even when trying numerous different paths for the linker. This library is very famous and is used often, so obviously it can work. I know 'similiar' questions have been asked, but my question is very specific, and still, following every instruction and guide I could on youtube and on this site, I can't set it right.

Would appreciate an explanation that picks off right at the start of the above 3 steps, and mentions exactly which paths I need to use. Or if I am missing something before that, point me in the right direction. I am almost 100% sure I mentioned each and every step that I did, without skipping any.

Comment: You need to add the actual *library* to link with. It's somewhere in the linker project settings (don't have access to VS at the moment so can't say exactly where).

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can't find this library anywhere. I went through the entire folder, but it's somewhat misleading. The closest I found is what I mentioned in the post, where there is an obj. file. I couldn't find any DLLs that are often shown in guides. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: How did you get the library? Just checked out the source from Github? Downloaded a pre-built binary? If you just checked out the source you need to build it first. Or to make it simpler, use one of the pre-built binaries available from the Githup repo page you link to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just cloned the repository. Didn't download anything, no pre-built binary. How do I build it? what does it mean? If I download the pre-built binaries and open them, there is just an .exe file there, no .lib or .dll